# Why are 'a' and 'asdf' parsed as a valid dates by PHP DateTime and strtotime?

Tags: php, validation, date, datetime

I am developing a web application using PHP. I have a date form which is being validated client side and then submitted via POST to be inserted into a database using a prepared statement.

I want to do server-side validation of the date in addition to the client side validation but I'm struggling to understand the behaviour of both `strtotime` and the `DateTime` class.

What rule allows both of these methods to convert the string `a` into today's date and `strtotime` to convert `asdf` into 1969-12-31? Using `date_parse` I see that `a` is recognized as a valid timezone (somehow) but there is no time associated with it. `asdf` is even more confusing because `date_parse` actually says `The timezone could not be found...` but it still comes up with 1969-12-31

I was planning on converting the string to a date and then testing to make sure the date is in a valid range but both `a` and `asdf` could pass this test. I know I can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` and specify the format that the client side code should be sending but I'm really just curious why these functions behave as they do?

Comment: what is the version of php you are using ? Is it less than **5.1.0** ?

Comment: Please note that getting `1969-12-31` is a different issue. If you feed a function that expects a Unix timestamp (e.g. `date()`) with invalid input and you live West to Greenwhich PHP will gladly cast it to integer; `0` is the Unix Epoch and your time zone will do the rest.

Comment: Here's [an online demo](https://eval.in/935583) of the `1969-12-31` side issue.

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### strtotime returns as -1

**strtotime function** - The function returns a `timestamp` on success, `FALSE` otherwise.
**Previous to PHP 5.1.0, this function would return -1 on failure.**

**Date function** - The function contains two parameters `format` and `timestamp`. Now depending on the timestamp integer field, the date will be created.

So, creating a date with timestamp as `0` will give `1970-01-01` and for `-1` will give `1969-12-31` and so on.

**Code Examples**

```
echo Date('Y-m-d', 0); // OUTPUT - 1970-01-01
echo Date('Y-m-d', -1); // OUTPUT - 1969-12-31
echo Date('Y-m-d', false); // OUTPUT - 1970-01-01
echo Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('a')); // OUTPUT - 2018-01-16
echo Date('Y-m-d', strtotime('asdf')); // OUTPUT - 1970-01-01
```

**Current Scenario**

Now, in your case, it seems the `strtotime` function failed and hence returning `-1` as the timestamp. Hence the date.

Refer [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for more info on `strtotime` function

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.0 but what you are saying does make sense.

Comment: Actually I figured it out, because of my timezone, (int) 0 is actually a few hours before 1970-01-01, hence the 1969-12-31

Comment: "0 will give 1970-01-01" is misleading. 0 is a fixed moment in time that maps to different local times. If you don't set a local time, PHP will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return of strtotime for errors, it returns -1 on error.

strtotime expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

In your case your date in invalid and you are using the -1 returned as and offset from January 1 1970 00:00:00.